# Show latest custom post types on dashboard

Tags: functions

I am using this code which shows latest posts on my dashboard but it doesn't work for custom post types. Would appreciate how to modify code.

```
function wps_recent_posts_dw() {
?>
   <ol>
     <?php
          global $post;
          $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5 );
          $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                    <li> (<? the_date('Y / n / d'); ?>) <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ol>
<?php
}
function add_wps_recent_posts_dw() {
       wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'wps_recent_posts_dw', __( 'Recent Posts' ), 'wps_recent_posts_dw' );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_wps_recent_posts_dw' );
```

In terms of database performance is this function going to be a strain or I shouldn't worry that much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default the paramater for `post_type` is `post`.

To include all the post type add the below to you arguements

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'post_type' => 'any' );
```

The above will include all the post_types including pages and custom post types and if you would to include specific post types use an array like

```
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'post_type' => array( 'post', 'movie', 'book' ) );
```

For more details check the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)**